# echo $values ['sqlcolumnname']; not returning a displayed value even though vardump $values works

Tags: php, sql, arrays, variables, echo

echo $values ['sqlcolumnname']; not returning a displayed value even though vardump $values works...
I am trying to have these values returned in a readable format on screen.
I'm probably missing something simple here but I'm very new to php... Thank you in advance

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","admin");
    mysql_select_db("smlc");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `service_times`");
    $values = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo $values ['service_times_title'];
    echo $values ['service_times_content'];
?>
```

The output of var_dump is :

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["Service_times_id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(24) "Regular Worship Services" ["Service_times_title"]=> string(24) "Regular Worship Services" [2]=> string(118) "Holy Communion: Sunday 8:30 a.m. & 11:00 a.m. Sunday School: 9:45 a.m. between services Nursery care is available." ["Service_times_content"]=> string(118) "Holy Communion: Sunday 8:30 a.m. & 11:00 a.m. Sunday School: 9:45 a.m. between services Nursery care is available." } string(118) "Holy Communion: Sunday 8:30 a.m. & 11:00 a.m. Sunday School: 9:45 a.m. between services Nursery care is available." string(24) "Regular Worship Services"
```

When i use var_dump($values['service_times_title']); the value returns NULL. I did try looping it with no effect. I thought I didn't really need it to loop as I only need the first row values.

(this was not done from a tutorial, however I have used one previously on other projects)
Thanks again

Comment: If it were only so simple. Use a loop-di-loop.

Comment: Did you follow a tutorial? If yes, any chance you can post the link? I'm asking only out of curiosity, @Fred-ii- already mentioned what the solution is.

Comment: Could you please add the output of var_dump? Is there any error otherwise? And what if you do `var_dump($values['service_times_title']);`?

Comment: your vardump shows that the key is `Service_times_title` not `service_times_title` try with the upper case S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Niko, after looking through Var_dump it turns out that I had my column headers missing Caps.